# How to detect pattern is required to unlock phone programatically in android?

Tags: java, android

As `LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED` has become deprecated: how can I check if the pattern is set as the preferred security mechanism to unlock the phone?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager I know very very little about Android development but a simple google search solved this.

Comment: @krflol: KeyguardManager gives information whether device is secured by any kind of security like PIN, pattern, password, etc. or not, but does not tell which 1 of those methods are used as preffered security by the user. I specifically want to know whether user has set "PATTERN" as preffered security method.